ChatMemberHandler Not Working with New Bot Token
I have a function that records a user entering a channel into the database, which is triggered by ChatMemberHandler with chat_member_types=ANY_CHAT_MEMBER. I've granted the bot all the necessary permissions in my four main channels where it's used.
The problem is that this functionality works perfectly with the old bot token but not with the new one (I changed the bot's username, hence the new token). When I run the code with the old bot token, it handles everything as expected. However, with the new bot token, it doesn't respond to users joining the channel.
Here are some steps I've taken so far:
Ensured both bots have identical permissions.
Removed the old bot from some channels and left only the new one.
Deleted the old bot entirely to avoid any conflicts.
Despite these steps, the new bot still fails to handle ChatMember updates. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

I found the solution. I don't know why, but I had to explicitly specify chat_member, in the list of allowed updates for the new bot token for it to handle them. I didn't had to do this with the old bot. If someone has an answer, I'd appreciate that, as I'm curios why it happens.
